# How to enable Upgrade in MSI Files using Microsoft Setup and Deployment Projects

Tags: windows-installer, visual-studio-setup-proje

Once my exe is installed, the next time when I go for the another installation,
It should go for the Upgrade Window.

But it says, Already Version Installed, Uninstall the Version.

How can I overcome this?

I had changed the Version numbers, (Minor, Major, Build)
Its doing the same.

Answer (score 0):

This covers the subject:

https://www.simple-talk.com/dotnet/visual-studio/updates-to-setup-projects/

Basically you need to increment the version of the setup project, accept the changes, and set RemovePreviousVersions to true. Also make sure that both the original and the upgrade are the same context (for example both are Everyone installs).

Since that article was written you now need to increment the file versions of the actual files you need updating.

Comment: Thank you , we will go through Link.